# Global typescript variable not updating after assignment it in subccribe

Tags: angular, typescript, scope

This is the Auth Service file in which I have assigned the token value to the global this.token variable, but I am not able to get the value of this.token outside the subscribe. As I am a newbie in this, please point out the mistakes I have done for this. Your answers would be very appreciated!

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from './user.model';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthService {

  private token: string;

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ){
  }

  getToken() {
    return this.token;
  }

  signup(username: string, email: string, password: string) {
    const user: User = {
      username: username,
      email: email,
      password: password
    }

    this.httpClient.post<{success: boolean, message: string}>('http://localhost:3000/signup', user)
    .subscribe((responseData) => {
      if(!responseData.success){
        console.log(responseData.message)
      }
      else{
        console.log(responseData.message)
      }
    })
  }

  login(email: string, password: string){
    const user: User= {
      username: null,
      email: email,
      password: password
    }

    this.httpClient.post<{token: string}>('http://localhost:3000/login', user)
    .subscribe((responseData) => {

      const auth_token = responseData.token;
      this.token = auth_token;
      console.log(this.token)
    })
    console.log(this.token)
  }

}
```

Comment: as per my understanding you will get value in this.token but there will be delay in because using subscribe in auth service. please share console.log and errors that will help us to understand the issue

Comment: The first console.log() gives the value of the token, but the second one after that gives undefined.

Comment: Because it's outside the async subscription

Comment: Yes @Phix, I learned that from google but I don't know how to get that value from async subscription. Can you state me the process to get that?

Comment: As per my understanding your this.token is updating there value but late due to asynchronous subscription. Try getter and setter for token